# AWS loadbalancer listner rule giving error 500 (internal server error) when creating from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, amazon-waf

Everything worked fine before setting up AWS Web Application Firewall (AWS WAF)

After this the cloudformation is not able to create the loadbalancer https listner rule. Looking at the docs, it said that 500 internal server can arise from AWS WAF configuration.

I removed the AWS WAF association from loadbalancer and deleted all the resources associated to AWS WAF. It still fails.

**The Exact Error:**
Internal failure (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure; Request ID: xxx-xxx-xxxx; Proxy: null)

Comment: Where did you find the exact error "Internal failure..."?

Comment: This was resolved. On looking into AWS personal health dashboard it was something related to that. Anyways, Thanks

Comment: I understand that the Health Dashboard showed an open issue, but my question was specifically where you saw the error message that you described above.

Comment: Well, I saw it in cloudformation events, when it get failed i saw the error there side by the resource ::listnerrule, create failed, internal server error. i hop that helps. or you can ask what is it that you really want to understand.